# HttpComponents PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager maxPerRoute and maxTotal?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpcomponents

Can someone please explain to me what `setMaxPerRoute(max)` and  `setMaxTotal(max)` do in reference to HttpComponents PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These settings control connection pool size.

- `setMaxTotal(max)` defines the overal connection limit for a conneciton pool.
- `setMaxPerRoute(max)` defines a connection limit per one HTTP route. In simple cases you can understand this as a per target host limit. Under the hood things are a bit more interesting: `HttpClient` maintains a couple of `HttpRoute` objects, which represent a chain of hosts each, like `proxy1 -> proxy2 -> targetHost`. Connections are pooled on per-route basis. In simple cases, when you're using default route-building mechanism and provide no proxy suport, your routes are likely to include target host only, so per-route connection pool limit effectively becomes per-host limit.

**Example:**

Suppose you have `setMaxPerRoute(5)` and `setMaxTotal(20)`. That means you can simultameously use up to 5 connections for every target host: 5 connections with google.com, another 5 connections with oracle.com and so on. The total amount of open connections can't however exceed 20 regardless of the number of hosts you're communicating with.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. Is there a limit to the <code>maxPerRoute</code>? As I will be trying to request a lot of URL's from the same website (tens of thousands) using roughly 150 threads.

Comment: Not in the HttpClient itself, it's perfectly ok for the client to have 150 connections to a single host. But keep in mind, that server may not allow so many connections from a single client, that depends on the server configuration.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but do you use HttpComponents yourself?

Comment: I do, my current project utilizes it heavily.

Comment: Do you mind me asking you some questions regard it and best practices?

Comment: @James, feel free to ask

Comment: @Jk1 Thanks for the explanation. Obviously the official document is a little bit vague. If the HttpClient only connect to one internal host all the way, is it ok to set the value of `setMaxPerRoute` and `setMaxTotal` to be equal, let say they are all 200?

Comment: I suppose it is, as long as your internal host is able to handle up to 200 connections.

Comment: when the app is in this state [total available: 5; route allocated: 50 of 50; total allocated: 18 of 100]  starts getting timeout, it has CloseableHttpClient, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with MaxTotal 100, DefaultMaxPerRoute 50 configured, also a ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy with 20 secs, what can be the error ?