# I want to use HttpClient4 to do our RESTful API stress testing for concurrent send request , Can I use one HttpClient instance?

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-httpclient-4.x

All

I want to use HttpClient4 to do our RESTful API stress testing by concurrently send request to target server , Can I use one HttpClient instance ?

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

whether it must let each concurrent thread to new different HttpClient instance ?

How to improve design to reduce client instance resource but keep the same concurrent number , such let 200 thread send each request concurrently .

Use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager it seems always can't concurrently execute .

Comment: But My question is How to let each thread concurrently send http request ? If I have 100 threads to start send http request with the same one httpClient instance , It will be OK？　ｏｒ　ｅａｃｈ　ｔｈｒｅａｄｓ　ｍｕｓｔ　ｎｅｗ　ｔｈｒｅａｄ－ｂａｓｅｄ　ｉｎｓｔａｎｃｅ　ｔｏ　ｓｅｎｄ　　？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use one HttpClient instance ?

It's perfectly ok to share single `HttpClient` instance between multiple threads. You may even have a single instance for the whole application.

> Use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager it seems always can't concurrently execute.

`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` is capable of concurrent request execution. May be you need to enlarge pool size using `setDefaultMaxPerRoute(...)` and `setMaxTotal(...)`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347350/httpcomponents-poolinghttpclientconnectionmanager-maxperroute-and-maxtotal/19347447#19347447) for the detailed description of how to use these settings.

To get more precise answer consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: But My question is How to let each thread concurrently send http request ? If I have 100 threads to start send http request with the same one httpClient instance , It will be OK？　ｏｒ　ｅａｃｈ　ｔｈｒｅａｄｓ　ｍｕｓｔ　ｎｅｗ　ｔｈｒｅａｄ－ｂａｓｅｄ　ｉｎｓｔａｎｃｅ　ｔｏ　ｓｅｎｄ　　？

Comment: It's OK, you can use the same HttpClient instance for all your threads

Comment: But one thread close httpclient , can  another thread use it again ?

Comment: In this case threads should not close() shared client instance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you need pc with a lot of thread. because even if you write in your code a bilion Threads, you can't tun it on your processor, because your processor have limit of core, and in same time work only X number of threads, where x core number in proccesor.
even if you run all this thread they wouldn't work at same time, they just will work in async way.

And also i recommend you don not image bicycle and use [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for testing.

Comment: Ｔｈａｎｋ　ｙｏｕ　，　Ｂｕｔ　Ｊｍｅｔｅｒ　ｓｃｒｉｐｔｓ　ｃａｎ＇ｔ　ｂｅ　ｒｅｕｓｅａｂｌｅ　ａｎｄ　ｇｏｏｄ　ｉｎ　ｍｙ　ｏｐｉｏｎ　．

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere, using a blocking client is not a good idea for stress testing as it stresses the client more than the server. A better choice would be to write your code using the AsyncHttpClient dependency. If you are on Eclipse, you could also try the [RequestAge plugin](https://github.com/mtopolnik/request-age), wherein you write your test scripts in Javascript.

Disclosure: RequestAge was written by the author of this answer.